# Bash script doesn't execute `export`

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm mading a bash file and I'm not expert. My goal is install some tools:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Install development settings | START"
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt autoremove -y

sudo apt install -y curl
sudo apt install -y wget
sudo apt install -y unzip

sudo apt install -y python3-pip python3-venv python3-dev build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev binutils

pip3 install --upgrade pip
export PATH="/home/max/.local/bin:$PATH"
pip3 install --upgrade wheel

curl -s https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
export PATH="/home/max/.local/bin:$PATH"

echo "Install development settings | END"
```

I don't understand why `export PATH="/home/max/.local/bin:$PATH"` isn't executed. Infact, at the end of the installation, if I write in the terminal `poetry --version` I see:

> Commando `poetry` not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install python3-poetry

But if I write `export PATH="/home/max/.local/bin:$PATH"` and again `poetry --version`, I see the correct output.

Comment: The commands will be executed. Place `set -x` at the top of your script, which will print every command before it's executed to see for yourself. It's to do with shell sessions. And if you want to permanently set environment variables you would need to set them in `.bashrc` which is run when a shell starts up (See [How to: Set environment variables in bash](https://devconnected.com/set-environment-variable-bash-how-to/)).

Comment: Your script almost certainly _is_ exporting those variables in the environment it provides its children.  Show us how you're testing.

Comment: You did not show how you executed your script. But if you place a `printenv PATH` at the end of the script, you should see the changed value.

Comment: I usually execute the script using `./script.sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly this is to do with how you are running the script.

If you are running

```
install_script.sh
```

Then the script will run in its own shell. i.e. the export works, but it does not affect the shell you are running it from, and changes are gone when the script ends and that process ends with it.

To run the script in the same shell you're currently in:

```
. ./install_script.sh
```

This should give you the results you're expecting.